# Htaccess mod_rewrite problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tuote/([^/]+) tuote.php?data=$1 [L]
```

it should change all `tuote/Something-Something` to `tuote.php?data=Something-Something` in server side (not redirect) but seems not to work (`$_GET['data']` gets no value).

And other question:
How could I make this `1-Something-title-nice-title` to go php

```
$first_part = "1";
$secnd_part = "Something-title-nice-title";
```

tried explode, but it does not work in this case.

**----EDIT----**
Thank you for replies.

I changed htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tuote/(.+) tuote.php?data=$1 [L]
```

but still `$_GET['data']` value is empty. BTW, I have other htaccess in parent directory, maybe it would affect in the code?

The other htaccess file has content:

```
<IfModule mod_php.c>
php_flag display_errors 1
</IfModule>

AuthUserFile /var/www/somepath/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile None
AuthName "Kirjaudu sisään"
AuthType Basic 

require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

And about 2nd question, it started to work. Thank you!

Comment: Now I added EDIT part there, please look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you do not have directory "toute". If you do, make sure you don't have .htaccess in there which would take precedence.
2. Create your rule match or sure. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$  route.php?data=$1 [L]` then see what's inside $_GET['data'], that should give you a clue about why your rule is not oring.

If it's not working, AllowOverride is not working. Confirm by misspelling directive in .htaccess without any effect on apache.

If you do get the string, try replace it with more strict rule.

---

For your second question, you can do this

```
list($id,$rest)=explode('-',$_GET['data'],2);
```

Alternatively you can have your regexp select separate parts of your URL into different variables $2 $3 etc.

Comment: RewriteRule ^tuote\.php/([^/]+) tuote.php?data=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

In your rewrite, all you're doing is checking for 1 or more occurrences of a forward slash. You need to change it to something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tuote/(.+) tuote.php?data=$1 [L]
```

For the 2nd question, looks like you're just trying to make a single string:

```
$both_parts = $first_part . "-" . $sednd_part;
```

Comment: That's not "1 or more occurences of a forward slash", that's "1 or more occurrences of whatever, but not a forward slash".

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteRule` seems fine -- make sure you are accessing the query string parameter correctly in your PHP code.

As for your other question, adding a `limit` to explode should do it:

```
list($first_part, $second_part) = explode('-', $string, 2);
```

See PHP documentation for [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more information.